# Generate C++ code for BNF grammar

Tags: c++, parsing, unicode, lexical-analysis, bnf

I have looked at the following software tools:

- [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/)
- [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)
- [BNF Converter](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/Cs/Research/Language-technology/BNFC/)
- [Boost::Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/)
- [Coco/R](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/coco/)
- [YACC](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Lex-YACC-HOWTO-5.html)

ANTLR seems the most straight-forward, however its documentation is lacking.
Ragel looks possible, too, but I do not see an easy way to convert [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) into its syntax.

What other tools are available that can take BNF input and generate a corresponding, Unicode-friendly, cross-platform, standalone, C++ parser?

Many thanks for all suggestions.

**Edit:** Changed Objective-C requirement to C++.

Comment: You should also consider time performance while selecting the tool.

Comment: You should look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961604/how-much-time-would-it-take-to-write-a-c-compiler-using-flex-yacc/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [boost.spirit 2](http://boost-spirit.com/home/).

The boost spirit user list is very active and answers are quick from the authors.

Answer (score 3):

[TDParseKit](http://www.parsekit.com/)!  (Most specifically, [this page](http://www.parsekit.com/grammars.html) on Objective-C parser generation with BNF grammars)

Comment: Conversion from BNF to the format required by a parser generator is generally a trivial task, even by hand.

Comment: Fair enough. Peter, I'll give Ragel another look.

Comment: Looks OS-specific; the tool should be cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [QLALR](http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Compilers/QLALR)? It is a creative Friday project from QtDF. I have not tried it personally, but the trolls seems to be pragmatic about their approach to problems, so I guess this is too.

Comment: Looks like it has a dependency on Qt.

Answer (score 1):

You can try GOLD Parser! It's a great tool for parsing and generating. With a simple UI, all what you need to do is to provide a valid grammar file and select your favored programming languages for your output code.