# Why can't LEX/YACC be used to parse C++ for a compiler?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I'm aware there's a reason but I haven't found a good, concise explanation as to why LEX/YACC cannot be used for C++.
I am also interested to know whether LEX/YACC could be used to parse Objective C, or whether that language suffers from the same problem. (Mind you I mean ObjC, not Obj-C++.) 
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1961604/139010

Comment: It's just the wrong tool for the job. YACC is an [LALR parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser) and C++ really needs a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). You can probably put a screw in with a hammer, but the result won't be pretty and it will take a lot of extra work.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: C++ does not *need* a recursive descent parser. It can be implemented with almost any parser technology.  The question is, "how much hacking?".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz:  You're the one making the (incorrect) assertion that C++ *needs* recursive descent.  Doing it with recursive descent isn't exactly pretty.   A GLR solution is much prettier and easier, and has zero hacking.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible to use lex and yacc to parse c++, but you need a lot of other machinery as well. At one time, gcc used a yacc-based parser, but it was replaced with a hand-built recursive descent parser which is believed to be easier to maintain, and which makes generating meaningful syntax errors simpler. clang uses a hand-built recursive descent parser for much the same reason.

Bison can build GLR parsers, which makes it a lot easier to explore alternative parses (necessary for disambiguation rules). See Ira Baxter's answer to [Are GCC and Clang parsers really handwritten?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319086/are-gcc-and-clang-parsers-really-handwritten) for some testimony about GLR parsing of C++.

Also see the links in Matthew Slattery's answer to the same question for some background on gcc and clang; in particular, a summary of costs and benefits perceived in 2008 for replacing the old yacc parser in gcc is found on the [gcc wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/New_C_Parser) (link copied from Matthew Slattery).

Comment: When gcc people say something is easier to maintain, that should be taken with a large sodium pellet.